# meaning of "zu Wort gelangen"

Tags: meaning, translation, phrase

I'm trying to understand sentences formualted with "etw. gelangt zu Wort" or "die Dinge gelangen zu Wort". These are:

> Es gilt vielen als philosophisch wertloses Kompilat, weil allerdings viele Denkrichtungen in ihm gleichzeitig zu Wort gelangen.

or

> Als geschliffener Autor und begnadeter Polemiker wird Debussy auch
>   selbst zu Wort gelangen.

Does it mean similar to "zu Wort kommen"? It seems to me that it might mean little different than that. What does it then mean exactly?

Comment: _zu Wort gelangen_ is not a common phrase. Could you provide more context for the first sentence?

Comment: The first passage is, "Es gilt vielen als philosophisch wertloses Kompilat, weil allerdings viele Denkrichtungen in ihm gleichzeitig zu Wort gelangen."

Comment: *gelangen* – *to reach*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "to have a say", i.e. to have the opportunity of talking.

Comment: That’s how I would understand it too, confirming the OP’s suspicion that it’s a synonym for »zu Wort kommen«.